# php include when hosting

Tags: php, html

My hostname is

http://gvidas.lhosting.info

Inside HEAD I have

```
<?php include("http://gvidas.lhosting.info/includes/header.php"); ?>
```

Physical location of that file is in /htdocs/includes/header.php

Why doesn't it work? Should I use relative paths?

Fragment of index.php

root/htdocs/index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION["admin_id"])) { redirect("managePage.php"); } ?>
    <?php $permision = "public"; ?>
</HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <...>   

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Fragment of header.php

root/htdocs/includes/header.php:

```
<?php require_once ("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once ("../includes/functions.php"); ?>


<?php $db = mysqli_connect('http://gvidas.lhosting.info/', 'user', 'pass', 'beta'); 
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { die("Database connection failed: " . 
        mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
        } 
?>
```

I now think I should use

```
 <?php require_once ("session.php"); ?>
```

innstead of

```
  <?php require_once ("../includes/session.php"); ?>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most live servers won't allow absolute including. You can update the code as follows:

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
```

The relative path will depend where you're including the file from. The above example assumes that the file in which this `include()` function is called from a file inside the web root.

Comment: Show your directory structure. Where are you calling the `include()` function from?

Comment: This is my structure: http://postimg.org/image/vge1ouy4h/ I'm calling it from index.php

Comment: OK, which file are you trying to include the `header.php` file into? Everything in root?

Comment: header.php is in folder includes, the full path to it is root/htdocs/includes

Comment: Yes, I can see that. My question is where are you calling the `include()` from? i.e. is it from `htdocs/index.php`?

Comment: Yes, index.php is in htdocs folder (all of my pages are there, and in includes folder are all files which I include).

Answer (score 3):

You should use physical location rather than URI.

```
<?php include("/htdocs/includes/header.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a internet address as path for includes/requires, use a physical path instead, like `/htdocs/includes/header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

 <?php include("$path/includes/header.php"); ?>
```